# VirtualBox and CentOS 6, cannot connect to httpd after reboot

Tags: iptables, centos6, httpd

VirtualBox and CentOS 6, cannot connect to httpd after reboot from host.  if I do a

**iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT**

then it works but everytime I reboot I have to log in as root and do this. how can I fix this so I dont have to do it after every reboot

Comment: have you save your iptables rules ? # service iptables save  or put on your /etc/rc.local

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Rikih said - run "service iptables save" after issuing the "iptables -I INPUT ..." command. That will save your ruleset to the /etc/sysconfig/iptables file, which is what is read at startup.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Rikih and John...but the anal retentive part of me says...
make a backup directory "mkdir /root/my_iptables_backups" and then 
"cp /etc/sysconfig/iptables /root/my_iptables_backups" ...to save the present working config.  Next run the iptables save command after you make your change (for the VM to work).  If you truly want to be anal retentive...run a diff on the two files...the old config in /root/my_iptables_backups and the new file...in /etc/sysconfig.  You should see that one entry.  If they are wildly different (and the they should not be), then you could just copy back your backup to /etc/sysconfig and try again.